# What is the correct xpath for the svg in the HTML featured in this example?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

so far I have the following code:

```
like_button =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="QBdPU "]/*[name()="svg"][@aria-label="Like"]')
like_button().click()
```

To correspond with the following HTML (I'm trying to click the svg section):
[image]

Was wondering if anyone could correct my xpath.

Comment: you may actually want to target the <button> tag.

Comment: `svg` node is not a *child* of `div`, but a *descendant*, so either replace `.../*[name()="svg"]` with `...//*[name()="svg"]` or add `.../span/...` between them as in [Jack Fleeting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436417/what-is-the-correct-xpath-for-the-svg-in-the-html-featured-in-this-example/64436456#64436456)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your xpath expression to

```
//div[@class="QBdPU "]/span/*[name()="svg" and @aria-label="Like"]
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Careful, `svg` elements are in an implied namespace in browser DOMs.

Answer (score 0):

As [kjhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436417/what-is-the-correct-xpath-for-the-svg-in-the-html-featured-in-this-example#comment113939851_64436456) mentioned in the comment, `svg` elements are in different namespaces of HTML, so we need to be careful when picking it via xpath.

I see that you're trying to get Like button on Instagram, I've tested this on Chrome, I think it will work on Selenium as well. Try:

`//*[name()="svg" and @aria-label="Like" and @height="24"]`

Remove `and @height="24"` if you also want to get Like button on comments. Like button on comment has `and @height="12"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To identify and `click()` on the *Like* button on *Instagram* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//button[@type='button']//span//*[name()="svg" and @aria-label='Like']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='button'] span > svg[aria-label="Like"]"))).click()
  ```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```